# Plot a 3-cycle graph with clockwise-directed edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks

When I try to plot a 3-cycle, the edge direction is always counter-clockwise. The plotting code is

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 0, 0 -> 2, 2 -> 1}, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 DirectedEdges -> True, PlotStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[White], 
     RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], Disk[#1, 0.15], White, 
     Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```

and the output

[image]

I have tried many ways to change the edge direction without success. Anyone can help with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You can use the option `VertexCoordinateRules`:

```
opts = {VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True, 
   VertexCoordinateRules -> {{0., 1.}, {1., 1.}, {.5, 0.}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}, 
   VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[White], 
       RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], Disk[#1, 0.15], White, 
       Text[#2, #1]} &)};
GraphPlot[{1 -> 0, 0 -> 2, 2 -> 1}, opts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or use `Graph` and give the vertices in the order you wish as the first argument:

```
opts2 = {VertexSize -> Medium,
   VertexStyle -> 
    Directive[EdgeForm[White], RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255]], 
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
   VertexLabelStyle -> {Directive[White, FontSize -> 16]}, 
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle"};
Graph[{0, 1, 2}, {1 -> 0, 0 -> 2, 2 -> 1}, opts2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Simply as an alternative you can interactively rearrange the nodes, but to do so you must avoid `VertexRenderingFunction`.  Here is an example:

```
postLabel[f_] := Text[Framed[n_, __], p_] :> f[p, n]

labelFn = {EdgeForm[White], RGBColor[113/255, 190/255, 236/255], Disk[#1, 0.15], White, 
    Text[#2, #1]} &;

GraphPlot[{1 -> 0, 0 -> 2, 2 -> 1}, VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}] /. postLabel[labelFn]
```

You can then click as necessary to enter the graphic and select a node, then drag to rearrange as desired.  Example result:

[image]

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8109449/618728

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Graph` and set explicit [`VertexCoordinates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexCoordinates.html).

```
g = CycleGraph[3,
  PlotTheme -> "CoolColor",
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Large, White],
  VertexSize -> 0.3,
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
  DirectedEdges -> True
 ]

{Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> CirclePoints[3]], 
 Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> Reverse@CirclePoints[3]]}
```

[image]